# Sqlalchemy, too many mysql connections

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

We use Sqlalchemy & flask.

It use QueuePool when create Sqlalchemy engin.

So the question is, we deployed service by gunicorn and run 16 work per  machine. When we had 80 machine, mysql had too many connections.

So, are there some solution to timely delete the idle connection

Comment: Commit / rollback, and close/remove the session at the end of a request, at least.

Comment: Yes, We remove the scoped_session when teardown. But the connection is going back to pool , not disconnected.

Comment: you can use NullPool to close connection automatically